# How to change a CAB file through .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, cab

I have a CAB file (actually a WSP, but I think they are the same) that contains several files.  One of the files is an XML that I would like to modify and re-insert into the CAB.

Is there anything that is built into .NET that will allow me to do this?  If not, are there any third party libraries out there that will help me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one cab compressions and extraction library:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/CABCompressExtract.aspx